# New PayPal API - how to set up live application? Not Sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

It has been some time since I last set up PayPal payments on a website.

After I opened the new PayPal API and honestly, I am a little bit confused. At the moment, there is each new website considered by PayPal support?

On the following page, https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications, I found **Test credentials**, but I want to set up **Live credentials**.

In the block with **Live credentials**, it is written:

```
Live credentials (currently for U.S. businesses)
We'll email you when your live credentials are ready.
```

How much it usually takes? And also, what everything is needed for being approved? Is there any way to make it faster or the only thing I can do is to wait?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question about new websites is unclear. But I would guess that the Classic APIs might be a better choice for your use-case, as the new RESTful API is still in a beta stage with limited features.

I see this is tagged as paypal-adaptive-payments.  Adaptive Payments is its own separate API and you can read information on going live with it here:  https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/going-live-with-your-application

For the second part of your question, I am not sure how long it takes but my best guess from similar processes is two business days (Monday-Friday)

Answer (score 1):

Live credentials are only available for US accounts right now as we currently only support America.